# Another shell open when at server?

Tags: bash, terminal, buffer

How can I have another Terminal open when I am at my server by ssh?

I do not want to type my password twice to get another terminal for my server.

Perhaps, Bash has buffers similarly as Vim.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out [GNU screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/). It's kind of arcane and awkward to use, but does what you're looking for, and it's probably also installed on your server.

You can also forward X11 and run multiple `xterm` instances, but that's a pain.

Your best bet, though, is your proverbial "type my password every time" solution: you should  set up SSH keys so you don't need to type your password every time and then just use multiple connections in Terminal tabs.

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like [GNU Screen](http://www.kuro5hin.org/story/2004/3/9/16838/14935).

Answer (score 2):

The Bash shell has a feature called Job Control that allows you to run and manage multiple processes. You can read about it here: http://commandlinemac.blogspot.com/2008/12/bash-job-control-fg-bg-jobs-and-ctrl-z.html

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to use [screen](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/screen/) to open other terminals without needing to authenticate again.

Screen can also detach so that you can leave terminal open after logging out and re-attach them later. I use this on my home server for keeping rtorrent open.

Answer (score 1):

[GNU Screen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen)

BTW. If you don't like typing passwords, [try PK auth.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell#How_SSH_uses_public-key_cryptography) 
[How it's done with PuTTy.](http://tartarus.org/~simon/putty-snapshots/htmldoc/Chapter8.html#pubkey)